# Evaluating Struts2 Function using IF TAG

Tags: struts2, ognl

I need to use Struts2 `<s:if>` Tag to evaluate a function return value from different JSP pages.

The function is implemented inside a Class, and I want to use it in different JSP pages

Example:

```
<s:if test="%isLogin()==true">dosomething</s:if>
```

Comment: You can put your method in base action class which all your actions classes will extend. But it is better to put that kind of logic into interceptor.

Answer (score 2):

```
<s:if test="%{isLogin()}">dosomething</s:if>
```

Or better yet:

```
<s:if test="%{loggedIn}">doSomething</s:if>
```

Naming matters.

Comment: thanks, i have a question regarding the way this tag works, assume that i have a jsp page which contains the if/else tag only, how does the call to the correct action is happening. in my example: how the system knows which controller to go to if there are no form in the page? for my case i want to display the login form if the return value of the function call is false.

Comment: @bogha Forms have nothing to do with it. Actions are pushed onto the value stack and accessible in the JSP. Action methods are accessed via OGNL expressions.

Answer (score 1):

*Don't fight the framework* and *Know your libraries*.

Stop a minute and learn how it works. Then you will probably have no need to change its behavior anymore, but if you will, you will know how to do it in the right way.

- If something is common to a lot of Action / JSP *AND* it is VIEW stuff (like providing data that must be drawn on every page), then put it in a BaseAction and extend it from the other actions.
- If something is common to a lot of Action / JSP *AND* it is BUSINESS stuff (like checking if the user is logged in or not), do it serverside, [with an an Interceptor](http://andrealigios.blogspot.it/2012/08/struts2-write-your-own-interceptor-for.html).

Never put logic in JSP, the JSP must not even be reached in that cases.

Some useful readings are:

[Introducing Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/introducing-interceptors.html)

[Interceptors](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/interceptors.html)

[OGNL](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/)

[OGNL Language guide](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/language-guide.html)

But I suggest a deep dive in the whole Struts2 documentation... you will get better code and will save a lot of time after few days...